# USB 3 incompatible

Tags: windows-7, usb

I have a cameo Silhouette 1. This is essentially a flatbed printer that moves a blade rather than a pen to cut intricate patterns in paper. Until my last windows 10 update, it worked fine.  Now it will not connect to the program that uses the hardware.

I have tried putting the program in "windows 8" compatibility to no avail.

I believe the cameo is incompatible with USB 3 or the USB 3 driver.  The cameo is a USB 1 and uses its own brand of cable.

I am not able to open up my cameo or computer.  No hardware changes.  (Yes, I'm a wuss.)

The support from Silhouette is to buy a newer model.  I'm on a fixed income, so that's out.

Thanx for any help.

Comment: USB is generally downward compatible. Since the printer is USB 1 (very old) the printer just may not be compatible.

Comment: Try experimenting with different versions of the cutter's driver: https://www.silhouetteamerica.com/software

Comment: You've tagged this Win7, but asking about Win10. The golden rule with legacy peripherals is 'make damn sure they can run on the new update before you update'. Unfortunately, Win10 has taken that out of your hands. It might be time to invest in a legacy machine you can keep this going on, Win7 or so - keep it off the internet as Win7 is going to go unsupported from next year.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with Windows 10 no longer supporting USB 1 devices over
USB 3, as described in the article
[Windows 10 1809 Update Impacting Some Silhouette CAMEO, Portrait Users](https://www.silhouetteschoolblog.com/2019/08/windows-10-1809-update-impacting-some.html?fbclid=IwAR3_YG65oy7MsFuuOkibVT3uD5I9DCVaB0L9Are4inBeeUGZJSbHC-fHH9Q).

The article quotes Silhouette America's official statement:

> As of August 1, 2019 Silhouette America is no longer able to support
>   USB connection between Windows 10 (1809, 1903, or above), particularly
>   USB 3.0, or other related newer hardware and the following Silhouette
>   models:
>
> - CAMEO 1
> - Portrait 1
> - Silhouette SD
> - Original Silhouette

The advice given is either to rollback Windows 10 to a version predating 1809
and blocking updates (not recommended at all),
or to try connecting the device to a USB 2 port.

If your computer doesn't have a USB 2 port but has an available PCI placement,
perhaps a solution would be to add a
[USB 2 card](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073TSC5GG)
to your computer, or perhaps use a
[USB 3 to USB 2 adapter cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00EOI3VC8)
(the links are examples only and are not recommendations).

Comment: The link is from some Silhouette place. Is there any pointer to the original Microsoft explanation of the issue?

Comment: @Ale..chenski: This text is quoted in several sources, but I haven't been able to find the original.